# Altium Camtastic Auto-Rout PCB Border is routing over edge of board

Tags: pcb-design, routing, altium

I typically draw rout tool paths by hand, but I though I would give Altium's built-in router a try.  The command I am talking about is Rout->Auto-Rout PCB Border within the CAM document mode.

The tool properly finds the board outline, but the resulting rout path (when I export Gerbers) is right on top of the board outline - not butting up to the board edge like I am used to seeing when I rout it manually.

Am I missing a setting or maybe just interpreting the rout path Gerber wrong?

I tried some different settings for the rout tool in Tables->NC Tools->Tool Compensation but it isn't changing what I get.

Does anyone who has used this feature have some advice about what is happening?

Comment: Just a thought - do you know if the Auto-Rout feature checks the DRC rules before proceeding? Maybe something related to a clearance rule isn't enabled. Also, your post made me open up Camtastic and explore - I've never used it for more than visual examination of Gerbers. Could you explain how come the auto-rout tool is greyed out for me - I must be opening the Gerber incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, Altium auto-router uses the DRC rules to determine how it should route (e.g. trace/space width, via sizes etc)  (EDIT: Oops I thought OP mis-spelled route, didn't realize he meant rout as in cutting)

Comment: I think this may have something to do with it:
http://173.160.155.213/database/onlinesupport/functions/NC%20Menu%20-%20Tool%20Compenstion.htm

Still unclear though.  I need to find out if my board house is going to know what to do with this...

Answer (score 1):

Most fabs cut to the centerline of lines in the outline layer, ignoring the line width.  If you are unsure, you can ask your fab to verify this, and put it in the README you send them with the files.

Comment: For the Rout tool, you'll need to be in NC Editor mode: View->NC Editor.  This will make the Rout menu active.